# Need to get TAG name by element name using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set of html elements and I named those for all input/select/textarea. Anyway the names are unique for each element.

Now I need to get the Html TAG (Input/Select/Textarea) by Element name.

For EX:

```
<input type="text" name="sample" />
```

I need to get the 'input' TAG by using element name 'sample'.

I dont want to mention the TAG name on selector part in jquery. I have only unique names to find the TAGs.

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `querySelector()` to retrieve the element and `tagName` to retrieve the tag name

```
document.querySelector('[name="sample"]').tagName.toLowerCase();
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/WMrRwo)

Comment: @Sankar: jQuery can't get the tag name. It has no API for that. It can select the elements, but you must ultimately abandon jQuery anyway, so why not altogether?

Comment: @fcalderan Thanks. Its working. ThankYou.

Comment: Downvotes for a vanillaJS lightweight and portable solution instead of jQuery? Really?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select them with the tag name and then the name attribute like this: `$('input[name="sample"]')`

```js
$('input[name="sample"]').val('Lorem Ipsum');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="sample" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.tagName`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[name=sample]').tagName);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="sample" />
```

Comment: No.  Javascript is also okay for me. I am happy with this code. Thanks.

Comment: ps.  If you wanted to do this with a jQuery selector, you can do this -> `$('[name="sample"]').each((r,el) => console.log(el.tagName));`

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can do this:

```
$("[attr='name']")
```

This will select the element you want.

If you want to do it in native js you would do this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("attribute name");
```

That will return an array, and in your case, you would have only one element in it, so the element you need would be x[0].

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('input[name="name_of_element"]')
```

same goes with select, textarea, etc.